# Core performance issue LINQ on Ubuntu Server C#

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I've got really bad performance issues when the code is executed on my Ubuntu server, or any other Ubuntu server (I've tried 3 different servers).

A bit of information: I've got a text file (40-ish MB) with items. I put every line of text file in a list (because I need every item), this happens in less than 100 ms. Then later I need a new list that only contains certain items that start with X or Y. I use LINQ to get this done:

```
List<string> secondList = ListItems.Where(x => x.StartsWith(X) || x.StartsWith(Y)).ToList();
```

This line of code in particular takes 0.5 seconds on my windows machine, but 9-15 seconds on the Ubuntu server (The Ubuntu server has way better hardware than my Windows machine).

I tried for-loops, foreach-loops but they all result in the same time (9-15). 
Everything else works perfectly fine and extremely fast. It's just this line of code that takes extremely long (compared to the rest of the code) on Linux machines.

Comment: This would not answer why is this taking so long on Ubuntu, but have you tried using regular expressions? BTW, take a look [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/6074).